# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 when spring app is hosted on localhost

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am trying to access a spring boot micro-service hosting on localhost but I am getting following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Following is my code to access the service:

```
    import axios from "axios";

export const addProjectTask = (project_task, history) => async dispatch => {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/board", project_task);
  history.push("/");
};
```

I have tried to search on the internet but I am not able to find any solution with the localhost. When I use the above URL in Postman it works fine so the URL is correct.

**Edit:**
Complete Error:

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:8080/api/board 400
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:86
wrap @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ projectTaskActions.js:4
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
(anonymous) @ redux.js:477
onSubmit @ AddProjectTask.js:31
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:389
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3287
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3259
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3514
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21871
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:795
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4267
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4189
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21887
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
```

Comment: Can you post the response from the actual request, or logs from the server?

Comment: I have added complete error in my post

Comment: Do you have access to the server log? BadRequest could be many things, missing parameter for example

Comment: Can you help me how can I get the server logs? I am running my springboot app in localhost on my mac